# Google cannot fetch my website

Tags: google-chrome, wordpress

Since yesterday I noticed Google shows my websites like show in the picture, I can visit it on Chrome but not in Edge or my iPhone (default browser) , someone who knows what to do?[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorry, that is www.denkheldermedia.nl

Comment: Interesting, I can view it on firefox, but not my iphone. Maybe you have a mobile version of your site that is messing up. Or mobile only code that makes it mobile friendly. This is where the problem likely resides.